# Array as an instance variable

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have an array(moduleList) as one of my four private instance variables within my class **CourseYear**. I want to be able to add the names of the objects of the array within a different class **CourseYearTestApplication**. so far for the **CourseYear** class I have:

```
public class CourseYear
{
    private String courseName;
    private int year;
    private String tutorName;
    private Module [] moduleList;

    public CourseYear()
    {
        courseName = "Default";
        year = 0;
        tutorName = "Joe Bloggs";
        moduleList = new Module[6];
    }

    public void setCourseName(String newCourseName)
    {
        courseName = newCourseName;
    }

    public void setYear(int newYear)
    {
        year = newYear;
    }

    public void setTutorName(String newTutorName)
    {
        tutorName = newTutorName;
    }

    public String getCourseName()
    {
        return courseName;
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public String getTutorName()
    {
        return tutorName;
    }
}
```

I know this is my add method but I'm not sure how to enter my array values(Strings) in the Test

```
public void addModule(Module module1, int index)
{
    moduleList[index] = module1;
}


public Module getModule(int index)
{
    return moduleList[index];
}
```

This is my **CourseYearTestApplication so far**

```
public class CourseYearTestApplication
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        CourseYear courseYear1 = new CourseYear();

        courseYear1.addModule(new Module(), 0);
        courseYear1.addModule(new Module(), 1);
        courseYear1.addModule(new Module(), 2);
        courseYear1.addModule(new Module(), 3);
        courseYear1.addModule(new Module(), 4);
        courseYear1.addModule(new Module(), 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array? It would be much more sensible to use a `List<Module>`. Even regardless of that, it's not clear what you mean by "I'm not sure how to enter my array values(Strings) in the Test"

Comment: I'm using an array because they are the guidelines in the assignment. I want to put 6 strings into the array from the TestAplication. for example 6 subjects( "maths" "english.... ) I'm sorry I'm finding it hard to explain

Comment: You don't want to put those into the array. You want to put those into the *module* objects (one per object, presumably).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use an ArrayList instead?  This will allow you to grow/shrink the array as necessary and will follow your API requirements nicely:

```
public class CourseYear {
    private String courseName;
    private int year;
    private String tutorName;
    private List<Module> moduleList = new ArrayList<Module>;
    ....

    public void addModule(Module module1, int index) {
        moduleList.add(module1);
    }


    public Module getModule(int index) {
        return moduleList.at(index);
    }


}
```

Comment: Oh, this is homework and they require you to use an array... disregard.

Answer (score 0):

What strings do you want to set? if it's the course year etc, then `courseYear1.setTutor("John");` is fine. But if you mean setting things in the array, you should use the access method, so `courseYear1.getModule(1).setSomething("this String");`

If it's something else you might need to be a bit clearer.

EDIT: from your comment sounds like your looking for something like:

`courseYear1.getModule(1).setModuleName("Maths");`

Answer (score 0):

Passing in `new Module()` is just one Module, not an array of modules. I would recommend instantiating `Module[length]` outside of the method call, and then passing in that array of `Module`.